# Node.js: Trying to run a production build gives this error: import _Promise from "../../core-js/promise"; SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, babeljs, hapi.js, core-js

I have a hapi.js backend with a Vue frontend (using Vue CLI). I am using Node version 12.10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Everything works fine during development mode. When I run my app through a build process, it builds without any errors. The problem happens when I try to run my app in production. These are my NPM scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:vue dev:hapi",
  "dev:vue": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "dev:hapi": "NODE_ENV=development node-dev --no-notify src/server/server.js --exec babel-node",
  "build": "npm-run-all --serial build:vue build:hapi",
  "build:vue": "vue-cli-service build",
  "build:hapi": "NODE_ENV=production babel src/server --out-dir dist/server --copy-files",
  "prod": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/server.js",
  ...
}
```

After running `npm run prod` I get this error in my terminal:

```
/path/to/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:1
import _Promise from "../../core-js/promise";
       ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This is my `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@vue/app",
    "@babel/preset-env",
  ],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
      corejs: 2,
    }]
  ]
};
```

I thought the `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugin was supposed to handle any issues I might have with Promises. Apparently Node v12 is supposed to support Promises out-of-the-box, but I am obviously still having problems.

Does anyone know what is going on in this situation and what I can do to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. I had to change the configurations in my `babel.config.js` file. I included the [babel `env` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#env) and defined separate configurations for the client and server. This is what my `babel.config.js` file looks like now:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    client: {
      presets: [
        "@vue/app",
      ]
    },
    server: {
      presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env",
      ],
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
          corejs: 2,
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
};
```